# Show line number of error in Yii 1.1.x

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

I have a self explanatory error in my Yii application - I know what the problem is, I would just like to know which line & file this is on.

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Can anyone explain the best/easiest way to use the Yii framework to output the exact line number that this error is coming from? I already have some debugging on but it all looks confusing and nowhere does it say Line xxx in file somename.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this Tutorial :

As you expected, this tutorial showing only file name and line number only.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/113/how-to-customize-error-handling-in-console-mode-applications/

Answer (score 0):

what about using these 2 lines on your index.php??

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

Comment: will give that a shot too